# Is it possible to branch a Bezier curve randomly?

Tags: bezier-curves

I am trying to make custom plants, and am wondering if there is a simple way to split/branch a curve, procedurally would be best. The Sapling addon doesn't really do what I need, but is the general sort of thing I want to accomplish (the *Branch Splitting* part).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try a [L-system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system). To use curves the way you describe it would require scripting.

There is a plugin for 2.6 available [here](https://github.com/ento/blender-lsystem-addon)

Related:

- [Algorithmic Botany](http://algorithmicbotany.org/papers/)