# Connect curve vertex to 3 other

Tags: bezier-curves

I am trying to model a tree with curves, and I need to extrude 2 paths from 1 vertex, but when I try to do it, it separates the vertex. If I try to join it with F, it says "Can't create a segment". 
Is it possible to make a branch with curves and why not?

[image]

Is there any workaround or addon? Because I need it with curves.

Comment: Curve can't split into 2, when extruding from the middle of the curve new unconnected curve [will be created](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/curves/editing/introduction.html#extrude-curve-and-move). This is likely a limitation of the curve object; either use 2 overlapping ones or convert to mesh and retopo the junction. Generally when creating trees some addons are used, e.g. Sapling, SCA Tree Generator (free ones) and more payed ones

Comment: Ok, that's not a tree, that's a grape stem. I've never used tree gen, but not sure if it's settings will suit for grapes.

Comment: I'm going to use your advice with using 2 overlapping curves.

Comment: related:[Is it possible to branch a Bezier curve randomly?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22961/is-it-possible-to-branch-a-bezier-curve-randomly) and [How to split one control end of bezier curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33535/how-to-split-one-control-end-of-bezier-curve) and [Branching Bezier Curves](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40343/branching-bezier-curves)